# How do I access the methods and Global variables of outer class from an inner class object, and if I cannot what is purpose of having an Inner class

Tags: java

```
public class StaticAndInnerClasses {
    String testString;
    class InnerClass{
    int x;
    int y;


    }
    static class InnerStaticClass{
    int a=10;
    int b=20;

    }
    public void changeCharacter(){
    testString="Characters modified";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
    StaticAndInnerClasses.InnerStaticClass statciClassObject=new StaticAndInnerClasses.InnerStaticClass();
    StaticAndInnerClasses outerObject=new StaticAndInnerClasses();
    outerObject.changeCharacter();
    InnerClass innerClassObject=outerObject.new InnerClass();    
    innerClassObject.changeCharacter();   



  }
    }
```

As you can see in my code that I have created a innerClassObject in the last line, now I want to know why I am not able to access the String testString using innerClassObject. isn't testString a Global variable and haven't I created the instance of innerClass within the outerClass .i.e "StaticAndInnerClasses" And if it is not possible then why have the Inner  Classes

Comment: What makes you think you can't?  There's nothing in your code that looks like it's trying to access this from the inner class object.

Comment: @DonRoby I was not able to call the methods or the testString.

Comment: @DonRoby This is what I have added in my code,
InnerClass innerClassObject=outerObject.new InnerClass();    
    innerClassObject.changeCharacter();

Comment: changeCharacter() is not a method in InnerClass.  See my answer, and perhaps it'll clear something up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code *inside* the inner class can reference the stuff in the outer class.

For this toy example:

```
public class StaticAndInnerClasses {
    String testString;
    class InnerClass{
        int x;
        int y;

        public void printString() {
            changeCharacter();
            System.out.println(testString);
        }
    }

    static class InnerStaticClass{
        int a=10;
        int b=20;

    }
    public void changeCharacter(){
        testString="Characters modified";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        StaticAndInnerClasses.InnerStaticClass statciClassObject=new StaticAndInnerClasses.InnerStaticClass();
        StaticAndInnerClasses outerObject=new StaticAndInnerClasses();
        StaticAndInnerClasses.InnerClass innerClassObject=outerObject.new InnerClass();
        innerClassObject.printString();

    }
}
```

So in the code of the inner class, you can reference methods and fields of the outer class, as is done here in the method `printString()`.  This does not turn the outer class methods into methods of the inner class so the code (in the outer class `main`)

```
innerClassObject.changeCharacter();
```

as you referenced in a comment, will not work.  It in fact won't compile.

Comment: OK thanks for the code I was trying to access the method in the outer class.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between an inner class and a *static* inner class.

A static inner class is not associated with any instance of the outer class, hence why you can't access the enclosing classes' fields.

However, a non-static inner class must be constructed using an instance of the outer class. So, your test code would look like:

```
OuterClass outer = new OuterClass();
InnerClass inner = outer.new InnerClass();//Yes, with that exact syntax!
```

*EDIT* For those saying the above does not compile, here's the exact message from Eclipse when trying to instantiate `InnerClass` directly:

> No enclosing instance of type OuterClass is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type OuterClass(e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of OuterClass).

Comment: Let me try. I think it didn't work but lets see again using your syntax.

Comment: this is what I added in my code but it is not working,
InnerClass innerClassObject=outerObject.new InnerClass();    
    innerClassObject.changeCharacter();

Comment: @DonRoby So I don't understand why have the InnerClass at all, because I don't see any errors in rest of the code.

Comment: @DonRoby It does indeed compile. If you have a *non*-static inner class, you have to invoke "new" via an instance of the outer class. If the inner class is static, then you don't need an outer instance, you just need to qualify the inner class (or import it directly).

Comment: Please show a bit more code for context.  As far as I can understand or see by actually compiling code, the `inner.changeCharacter()` can never work if `changeCharacter()` is a method in `OuterClass` and not `InnerClass`.  This method call is why I say it won't compile - your construction of the `InnerClass` instance is correct.

Comment: Ah, I see -- I misread the original question. I thought `changeCharacter()` was a method in the inner class, demonstrating that the `testString` was modified.

Comment: It might make sense to edit the answer to reflect your new understanding, or delete it if you can't edit it in a way you think is useful.  But I'll anyway retract my downvote.